# How do I post an input whitout a form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm using Bootstrap as my framework, and I don't like what happens with my column if I put it in a `<form>` tag. So, can I post my input to a php file without a form?

**HTML**

```
<form role="form-horizontal" id="usr_reg_in" name="usr_reg_in" action="php/usr_time_reg.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reg_in" name="reg_in" placeholder="Var god ange anst. nummer">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">In</button>
        </span>
</form>
```

Comment: you can with ajax yes, you'd need to do a http post request in javascript. OR use formdata

Comment: So that's the only way? i can't use like data-target in the input, or grab the values with the button or something else fancy?

Comment: "grab the values with the button" then what? you'll still need a http request or use the formdata api

Comment: As the form is posting to another page, when is your form getting messed up? is it being redirected back?

Comment: *What* happens with your column? Please post code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: There is no really problem. It´s just a question. Can i some how post the input without a form tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. For example, you could use [jQuery's Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method.

But `form` tags are here for a reason, and they should be used accordingly. Layout shouldn't be an issue for dropping a form.

Ask a question about the form breaking your layout here in SO. I'm sure it's quite simple to fix it.